# how to add Indian rupee symbol in prestashop

Tags: prestashop

how to add indian rupee symbol to prestashop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you include a custom CSS stylesheet to your PrestaShop deployment? Perhaps JavaScript is an option for you?

This article shows how to do both: [How to Add India Rupee Font Symbol](http://www.quickonlinetips.com/archives/2010/08/add-india-rupee-font-symbol-in-blog-posts/)

Answer (score 1):

visit this site, http://webrupee.com/

and add the javascript code into the  section of your themes/prestashop/header.tpl

Answer (score 1):

If you have any font which supports unicode standard you can add the rupee symbol easily by holding the ctrl+shift keys and typing u20b9 which is the unicode value for the symbol.
In prestashop just go to payment > currencies and edit your currency and use the above key and character combination in the space provided for the currency symbol.

Ubuntu font has built in support for the rupee symbol.

Late reply i know but i was struggling with this problem for some time and found this just today. Hope someone finds it. This is the best and simplest way to add the symbol insead of using some third party website API which might be risky for a commercial website.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put unicode of ruppee sign in back office.
While displaying convert that into html unicode.
Or you can display Rs.
we at http://www.mebelkart.com does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In your shop database search for " _currency" table.In the same table change the value of "sign" field to "&#2352" without quotes.
It will work for the shop.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by adding javascript code the header.tpl
Or you can change the value of "sign" field to in the _currency table to "&#2352".

We at [trodly.com](http://trodly.com) are also doing the 2nd thing.

Comment: While the answer might be helpful, providing a link to your own site can be regarded as spam if it is not much related to the problem